# Remove (stop?) line-by-line RMarkdown output in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Setup:

- RStudio 1.1.453
- R 3.4.4

**Test.Rmd**:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "August 27, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
3*4
```
````

Put the cursor on the line with `3*4` in it and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` (on Windows) to execute it:

[image]

How can I suppress the output circled in blue above from appearing? This gets particularly annoying when I'm running multiple chunks of code, and I don't need to see the output for every chunk. Getting the variables via the console is enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the gear icon next to "Knit" and choose "Chunk Output in Console".

[image]